# How to fix URL if deleted in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

its my URL http://localhost/ci_sai/home/detail/berhalusinasi-adik-bunuh-kakak-sepupu

how to redirect to ERROR 404 if this link deleted to http://localhost/ci_sai/home/detail/berhalusinasi-adik-bunuh

I am using codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (example):

```
public function detail($slug='')
{
    $page = $this->db->get_where('pages',['slug'=>$slug])->row();
    if(!$page) {
        show_404();
        return;
    }       
    [...]
}
```

OR

```
public function detail($slug='')
{
    $page = $this->db->get_where('pages',['slug'=>$slug])->row();
    if(!$page) redirect('home/detail/berhalusinasi-adik-bunuh');    
    [...]
}
```